# IIS AuthorizaUser Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My .net mvc application is running on IIS, in release mode, when I try to access a page, it shows "An error occurred while processing your request."

After I remove the role from AuthorizeUser as shown below, I can access the page. Can anyone give advice?

Fail:

```
[AuthorizeUser(Roles = Role.User1)]
public class TestController : Controller
```

OK:

```
[AuthorizeUser]
public class TestController : Controller
```

Comment: Have you tried settings Roles equal to a string you know should work?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your AD does not have roles User1.

Please go through the following link to get a better idea.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dd460317(v=vs.100)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it by adding these lines into web.config:

```
<modules>
<remove name="RoleManager" />
</modules>
```